# Eclipse Juno No Debug Toolbar?

Tags: java, eclipse

I just upgraded to Eclipse Juno but I found there is no debug toolbar (Resume/Step into/Step over/Stop etc.) in Debug perspective?? How can I find the toolbar back? Thanks!

[image]

In the previous version:

[image]

Answer (score 194, accepted):

Here's where you find the menu to turn it back on:
[image: juno enable debug toolbar]

Comment: Although behavior is to show these items in the global toolbar now, the global toolbar has so many issues with rendering buttons properly currently that this is a nice fallback to know about.

Comment: @EdGruberman - can you elaborate on the global toolbar issues, or link to bug reports. I am having sporadic issues with global toolbar buttons suddenly jumping around! It's driving me mad! Very reassuring to know find out I am not the only one. I have searched for a bug report in vain. Juno 4.2

Comment: Debug tool bar did not show up even after trying this. Tool bar showed up after I restarted Eclipse.

Answer (score 30):

From the [Juno documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/whatsNew/platform_whatsnew.html?cp=0_6_3#Debug):

> To improve the presentation of the Debug perspective, the common debug
>   control commands (Stop, Resume, etc.) have been moved out of the Debug
>   view and into the global toolbar.
>
> The global toolbar can be customized with the Window > Customize
>   Perspective... action to add or remove debugging commands, or to
>   show/hide the debug toolbar completely.
>
> Old toolbar behavior can be restored by first toggling the Show Debug
>   Toolbar option in the Debug view's menu, then by disabling the Debug
>   toolbar from the Customize Perspective dialog.

[image: Global Toolbar]
[image: Show Debug Toolbar]

Comment: Thanks for the info. I can add the global toolbar by Window > Customize Perspective... but only for once. Once I changed perspective, it would disappear again and customizing with the Window > Customize Perspective won't work unless I restart Eclipse. I don't see any Debug view's menus as in the screenshot....Juno really sucks. It's freaking me out.

Comment: Glad you found it, no need for me to install the 4.2 version (yet)!

Comment: @tkotisis where is the 'global toolbar'?

Comment: @likejiujitsu Updated the answer to include images from Eclipse Help. Should be clear now.

Answer (score 12):

Since a month or so ago in Juno and now Kepler, my global menu was missing the debug buttons and wouldn't apply or save changes from Customize Perspective. broc.seib's workaround worked, but I wanted to fix the actual problem. **I found the file to be stored at workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml. Deleting (or renaming) the file reset my perspectives and fixed the issue with changes not saving.** However, the file apparently doesn't get recreated, so I assume Kepler saves it somewhere else and only read the old one for backward compatibility; correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You are right. The workbench settings for Eclipse Juno/Kepler are stored at `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi`.

Comment: Maybe a bit old to reply but when I removed this file from that folder and started eclipse, the debug buttons show up in my global menu. Definitely working for me

Answer (score 8):

Another way to enable the debug icons in the toolbar is to select **Window** -> **Perspective** -> **Customize Perspective** (or right click on the Perspective icon and select Customize). Then in the new pop-up window select **Action Set Availability tab** > **enable Debug** in the list on the left hand-side.

Once you do the above, right **click on the Debug perspective icon** -> **Save As...** -> name Debug, click save, OK to overwrite.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In Debug window there is this drop down menu (indicated by small rectangle) check the option "Show Debug Toolbar", that was the problem in my case

Comment: That helped me, thanks! Shouldn't it be enabled by default? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure they're checked in the 'Customize Perspective' dialog under toolbar visibility and Command Groups Availability.

Comment: It only works once after checking it in the dialog....If I changed perspective, it disappeared again and the dialog also doesn't work anymore....

Answer (score 0):

After a (re)search I've finally realized that this option (run\debug actions toolbar) was simply non-existant in Eclipse Helios. The most similar configuration for me was to

a. separate Debug view from other tabs 
 b. dock it above all other debug panels (Variables, Console, whatever
 c. minimise it's size to leave only the header with title and actions toolbar

I am posting it here instead of asking the same question about Eclipse Helios with the obvious "not such thing" answer. Hope it helps the next user of older Eclipse versions passing by.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Kepler eclipse version, debug toolbar can be made visible using  Eclipse->Window->Show Toolbar

Answer (score 0):

start eclipse with -clean flag, this works for me when upgrading from oxygen.0=>oxygen.1

Answer (score -2):

Before was not possible to see debug tool bar, after

```
 Window->Reset Perpective
```

was possible to show it again