# eclipse: debug toolbar disappears in debug perspective

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I'm having an issue with the debug toolbar disappearing from the global toolbar in the debug perspective in eclipse.  Here is what I want:

[image]

but here is what I get:

[image]

You can see the toolbar is available in the debug view, but when I load the type heirarchy it is not accessible, or if I close that view, or move it around the toolbar moves with it.

I can enable the toolbar once by customizing the perspective and enabling it in action set visibility:

[image]

but when I close the perspective and reload it goes away again, even if I save the perspective.

basically I'm trying to do the opposite of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436337/eclipse-juno-no-debug-toolbar)

Comment: I have the same issue. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

PyDev was accountable for this happening to me. For me the only solution was to uninstall the plugin (keeping a separate installation of eclipse for that for now). See the bugreport here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=491553