# can't edit toolbar in Eclipse-based IDE

Tags: eclipse

I'm using IBM Rational Developer for i 9.1.1.1.
In some way I caused situation that I can't show debug icons on toolbar.
When I use *Customize Perspective...* -> *Tool Bar Visibility* **Debug** is checked. When I uncheck it, it does not have impact on this setting - when I go there again, checkbox is still checked.

What I try:

- restart Eclipse
- restart computer
- *Reset Perspective...* option (it doesn't affect toolbar at all)

The question is of course how to enable debug icons (only for specific perspective).
I'd rather like to no reinstall the whole Eclipse to not lose another settings and it's not simple process for me.

Comment: Check debug output window. There you will see "Show debug toolbar" option.

Comment: @ChandanaKumara, how to go to debug output window?

Comment: You will see bottom of the eclipse.

Comment: @ChandanaKumara, I think I see what you writing about, however this window is not at the bottom. But I don't see this option there.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436337/eclipse-juno-no-debug-toolbar

Comment: Thanks... It worked.
First I can enable buttons on debug window, but I want to have them on general toolbar. To reach this, I had to reset settings by the way in this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17426876/2147927. Still if I disable debug icons, they disappear and then shows in settings as enabled, but resetting it will me enough for me for now. I guess this is some bug in Eclipse. Maybe you want to post your solution as answer so I can accept it? :)

Comment: Great. It has fixed that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset toolbar settings in eclipse by deleting or renaming **workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.ui.workbench/workbench.xml** and restart eclipse.

Comment: I changed answer.

Comment: OK. You don't have to write this because edit history is visible here.

Comment: Thanks your comment.